# IE Conditional statements in HTML are being removed?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, ie-developer-tools

So I'm seeing something quite weird. I'm running Windows 8.1/IE11, not sure if that is important or not.

I've inserted the following html comments. One is pulled straight from the HTML5 boilerplate so I'm sure that's right at least.

When I open up the dev tools, I can see the comments in the DOM in IE11 and with the emulator to IE10. As soon as I go to IE9 or below in the emulator with document mode and user string. All of the conditional IE HTML comments you see below and just the conditional IE comments are for some reason no where to be seen.

Has anyone ever seen anything like that? Have any clue why it might happen? I've searched exhaustively to no avail.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.PlatformModel.PlatformTitle </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="~/Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/platform/css/ie78.css"/><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>@Styles.Render("~/Content/platform/css/IE78.css")<![endif]-->

<!--// kendo common, kendo theme-->
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo-common-styles")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo-theme-styles")

<!--// platform -->
@Styles.Render("~/Content/platform-styles")

<!--// page styles -->
@RenderSection("styles", required: false)

</head>
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I wonder if they are being read and processed...?

Comment: "nowhere to be seen", how is that? You can find the contents created by those [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from `body` section... IEs>9 don't let you to create displayable elements to the `head` section, hence they are automatically moved to the `body`. Notice, that the emulation mode is not perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to update Windows and install the latest patches. The F12 tools in IE11 at RTM shipped with a bug* where the emulated document modes wouldn't respect conditional comments. That's since been fixed.

* http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806767/conditional-comments-do-not-work-when-emulating-document-modes-via-f12-developer-tools